# Sorting a list in python with the last numeric part + static string

Tags: python-3.x, string, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of directories by its sizes but if there is a number within the name it would take it up the sorted(by size) list

```
def num_sort(size):

    return list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+ ', size)))[0]

ab.sort(key=num_sort)

print("The top 5 folders in your directory and their size are : ")

print(ab)

print("The top 5 directories with the largest size are: ")

for i in range(1,6):

   print(ab[-i])
```

Here are examples:

```
Wanted output:
Dir1 20 MB
Dir2 15 MB
Dir3 10 MB
Dir4 5 MB
etc...
```

```
Current output:

Dir50 0 MB
Dir1 20 MB
Dir2 15 MB
etc...
```

Comment: So do you want to sort this list: `lst = ["Dir2 15 MB", "Dir1 20 MB", "Dir3 10 MB", "Dir4 5 MB"]` ? What if directory doesn't have a number?

Comment: I want the directories to be sorted by their size, the problem is when the directory has a number in its name and if its big it will take the directory up the list although it might not be large in size

Comment: For example: lst = ["Users 150 MB" , "Dir20 75 MB", "Dir1 50 MB" Dir550 25MB"]

Comment: Right now it would sort it by any number within the index: lst =  [ "Dir550 25MB" , "Users 150 MB" , "Dir20 75 MB", "Dir1 50 MB"]

Comment: Do you have only sizes in `MB`? Or are there other sizes in `KB`, `GB`, .. ?

Comment: only in MB what I did is when I got the size of the directories in bytes I divided the by (2 ** 20)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module to extract the correct number:

```py
import re

lst = ["Dir200 15 MB", "Dir1 20 MB", "Dir3 10 MB", "Dir4 5 MB"]

pat = re.compile(r"(\d+)\s*MB\s*$")

lst.sort(key=lambda v: int(pat.search(v).group(1)), reverse=True)
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```py
[
  'Dir1 20 MB', 
  'Dir200 15 MB', 
  'Dir3 10 MB', 
  'Dir4 5 MB'
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you can explain to me what you did I would really appreciate that, I am new to python

Comment: @martino I'm using pattern `(\d+)\s*MB\s*$`, the key part is the `$` at the end. `$` means end of string in this case. So I want to match the last number before MB. https://regex101.com/r/ZnVZkM/1